# Why is there no affect on lambda rendering speed after using webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, webpack

Hi I'm applying webpack on a project that uses microservices, nodejs, typescript, aws, aws-sam. The ultimate goals:

- Lower the cold start time of lambda functions.
- Using techniques such as tree-shaking and minification, security vulnerabilities can be reduced.
- Locate better transpilers, such as babel/ webpack, to reduce transcript compile time

However, after using webpack to minimize the file size of the transpiled js code, when I send an API request, the overall api rendering time, cold start time, and warm start durations remain unchanged. I'm wondering what I missed with this webpack usage on the nodejs backend. Here I'm mentioning what I've done so far with webpack and the results I've got.

---

I choose the investor microservice to use webpack. Because my lambdas have two layers, I was expected to apply webpack to both layers. Initially I used webpack on the first layer, which comprises the typical development code for investors. Here were my steps:

1. Install Webpack and other relevant dependencies

```
npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli ts-loader webpack-node-externals glob
```

2. Configure the `webpack.config.ts` to handle multiple entry points. Dynamically include all handlers in the `src` directory as an array and use this array as the entry point to webpack.

```
import path from 'path';
import { Configuration } from 'webpack';
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals';
import glob from 'glob';

interface EntryPoints {
  [key: string]: string;
}

const entryPoints = glob.sync('./src/**/*.ts').reduce((acc, path) => {
  const entry = path.replace(/(\.\/src\/|\.ts)/g, '');
  acc[entry] = path;
  return acc;
}, {} as EntryPoints);

const config: Configuration = {
  entry: entryPoints,
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
};

export default config;
```

since I'm using aws-sam and defined all the lambda functions in the template.yml I had to define all the handlers as entry points in the config. final output goes to lib folder, which was also previous output folder without webpack (only ts compiling)

3. Modify `package.json` as

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.ts"
}
```

4. update `tsconfig.json` Changes:

[image: tsconfig.json]

- Changed the baseUrl from ./src to ./. This allows TS to correctly resolve the webpack.config.ts which is not in the src directory.
- Added strict: true to compilerOptions to enable strict type-checking.
- Added webpack.config.ts to the include array to ensure TS includes Webpack config file when compiling.

---

Next, I added webpack to the second layer, which uses runtime dependencies as well as all of the code components shared by all microservices.  With the exception of one minor adjustment, I followed the methods outlined above for applying webpack. Because this layer does not generate any handlers from `template.yml`, I provided a single entry point for the webpack, which was the `index.ts` file.

Finally, I successfully built the code with webpack, then minified and tree-shaked the compiled JS code. After deploying the code to aws-lambda, I tested the REST APIs with Postman. Here are the results I obtained from aws-cloud-watch without webpack, with webpack on the first layer, and then with webpack on the second layer.

---

[image: results-image]

***Cold Start*s**:

With Webpack:

- 523.76 ms - **first lambda instance**
  Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 317 MB Init Duration: 3813.10 ms
- 579.93 ms - **second lambda instance**
  Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 315 MB Init Duration: 4403.64 ms
- 518.84 ms - **third lambda instance**
  Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 314 MB Init Duration: 4353.42 ms
- 547.41 ms - **forth lambda instance**
  Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 317 MB Init Duration: 4509.15 ms

  average - 542.485 ms

  Without Webpack:
- 535.31 ms - **first lambda instance**
  Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 315 MB Init Duration: 4337.82 ms
- 574.86 ms - **second lambda instance**
  Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 316 MB Init Duration: 3794.39 ms
- 584.82 ms - **third lambda instance**
  Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 319 MB Init Duration: 4270.62 ms

  average - 564.997 ms

**Further Improvement of the ticket: Apply webpack on layers.**

- output folder size reduced from 5.9M to 624K. percentage reduction: **89.67%**. whole lib folder converted into a single minified file: main.js
- couple of lambda instances with cold/ warm start times:

```
cloudwatch stream: **first lambda instance**
Duration: 288.00 ms Init Duration: 4446.59 ms
Duration: 324.01 ms
Duration: 185.15 ms
Duration: 43.84 ms
Duration: 287.02 ms
Duration: 174.80 ms
Duration: 342.89 ms

cloudwatch stream: **second lambda instance**
Duration: 542.30 ms Init Duration: 4410.09 ms
Duration: 426.63 ms
Duration: 156.00 ms
Duration: 264.56 ms

cloudwatch stream: **third lambda instance**
Duration: 342.21 ms Init Duration: 4383.47 ms

cloudwatch stream: **forth lambda instance**
Duration: 600.33 ms Init Duration: 4488.37 ms
Duration: 276.63 ms
Duration: 216.97 ms
Duration: 274.15 ms
```

---

**Conclusion:**
According to these results, cannot make a specific decision about the rendering time of lambda using webpack, and can't observe the lambda cold/warm start time has been reduced.

However the package sizes were reduced after applying webpack to the second layer, but my ultimate goal which was to Lower the overall API rendering time, cold start time, and warm start durations wasn't succeeded.

I have a bad feeling I've missed any step/s in this procedure. Please explain what I missed or any method I followed wrong. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Minifying and bundling your Lambda code has very little effect on the execution speed because all code is cached in memory when running the Lambda. Normally this helps to reduce the execution time because a client has to spend less time fetching the code before executing it, but in a serverside environment like Lambda this is not needed.

Comment: How are you saying that techniques such as minification and tree shaking (what webpack is using) have no effect on NodeJS lambdas? Do you have any sources to back this up? My issue is why, despite webpack's ability to minimize package size in lambda layers, the rendering time has not changed considerably.

Comment: @Damika because like I said all the code is loaded into the RAM at once when the function runs. So there is no disk IO or network traffic needed to fetch the execution code. Therefor it does not matter if your code is 10MB or 50MB, because there isn't any tranfer time.